# How to take the 10 last values from a file in awk

Tags: awk

I have a file that contains this data:

```
345
234
232
454
343
676
887
324
342
355
657
786
343
879
088
342
121
345
534
657
767
```

I need to cut the last 10 values and put it in another file:

```
786
343
879
388
342
121
345
534
657
767
```

Answer (score 6):

No need to use awk, just tail the data:

```
tail -n 10 input.txt > example.txt
```

If you really wanted to use awk, you have to keep track of the 10 last lines (`$0`) and print them in `END`. Though this would be overkill.

Comment: your awk version is still using tail

Comment: @MatthiasVallentin +1 for suggesting the right tool for the job, though since it is last `10` lines, we can avoid stating `-n 10` because that is `tail's` default behavior.

Comment: @JS웃 *(plus the other 4 people who upvoted)* did I not suggest the right tool for the job **and** actually answer the question asked?

Comment: @sudo_O I guess so. Though I felt the whole `awk` part wasn't really necessary.

Comment: @JS웃 The question is how to do it **with** `awk`. How can the `awk` part be unnecessary!?

Comment: @sudo_O True, though I believe OP isn't aware of all the tools that *nix offers. If he indeed has to do this in `awk` your answer will definitely be chosen as the best answer.

Answer (score 2):

This is what the `tail` command is for:

```
$ tail -10 file
786
343
879
088
342
121
345
534
657
767
```

To store the output in a new file use to redirection operator:

```
$ tail -10 file > new_file
```

However if you really want to do it with `awk` then the brute force approach is to store each line in an array and print the last 10 elements at the end of file:

```
$ awk '{a[NR]=$0}END{for(i=(NR-9);i<=NR;i++)print a[i]}' file
786
343
879
088
342
121
345
534
657
767
```

Again, to store the output in a new file use the redirection operator:

```
$ awk '{a[NR]=$0}END{for(i=(NR-9);i<=NR;i++)print a[i]}' file > new_file
```

---

The previous method is a very inefficient method as we have to create an array the same size as the file we are reading. A much better approach is to use the modulus operator to just create an array of size 10 containing the last 10 lines read:

```
$ awk '{a[NR%10]=$0}END{for(i=NR%10+1;j++<10;i=++i%10) print a[i]}' file 
786
343
879
088
342
121
345
534
657
767
```

This can be generalized to the last `n` lines like so *(i.e n=3)*:

```
$ awk '{a[NR%n]=$0}END{for(i=NR%n+1;j++<n;i=++i%n) print a[i]}' n=3 file 
534
657
767
```

Comment: POSIX mandates `tail -n 10` over plain tradittional `tail -10` IIRC.

Comment: That may be the case but I can't remember ever using a `tail` that required it. I guess that inclusion of `-n` is what deems @Matthias Vallentin worth +5 even though he didn't actually answer the question.

Comment: +1 for answering what was asked for and providing a better alternative. Sometimes I wonder how folks upvote the 2nd best answer and overlook the best one.

Answer (score 0):

Code for GNU [sed](/questions/tagged/sed):

- get the last 10 lines

  ```
  sed ':a $q;N;11,$D;ba' file
  ```
- get all but the last 10 lines

  ```
  sed ':a $d;N;2,10ba;P;D' file
  ```